# Trouble with lists combinations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

I have some Python lists with information that I would like concatenate. Those lists are similar to these:

```
vars1 = ["x1", "x2"]
vars2 = ["y1", "y2"]
main_list = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

What I want is to get all possible combinations (even I don't know the correct operation's name) to cover all cases what I put below:

```
[
    ("x1,a,x2", "y1,a,y2"), ("x1,a,x2", "y1,b,y2"),
    ("x1,a,x2", "y1,c,y2"), ("x1,a,x2", "y1,d,y2"),
    ("x1,b,x2", "y1,a,y2"), ("x1,b,x2", "y1,b,y2"), 
    ("x1,b,x2", "y1,c,y2"), ("x1,b,x2", "y1,d,y2")
    ("x1,c,x2", "y1,a,y2"), ("x1,c,x2", "y1,b,y2"),
    ("x1,c,x2", "y1,c,y2"), ("x1,c,x2", "y1,d,y2"),
    ("x1,d,x2", "y1,a,y2"), ("x1,d,x2", "y1,b,y2"),
    ("x1,d,x2", "y1,c,y2"), ("x1,d,x2", "y1,d,y2"),
]
```

I investigated about `itertools.product` function but I can't get the desired result.

I will appreciate if you could help me.

Comment: Read the documentation on the `itertools` package.  Write some code to attack the problem.  Use this to refine your question.

Comment: That pattern doesn't make much sense.  It's not all combinations.

Comment: @Prune I was reading about the library and I found the `product` function but I couldn't find a good example :( 
@hpaulj thank for the aclaration, I have to read more about that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but this looks like what you want (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
vars1 = ["x1", "x2"]
vars2 = ["y1", "y2"]
main_list = ["a","b","c","d"]
result = []

for a1, a2 in itertools.product(main_list, main_list):
    result.append((','.join((vars1[0], a1, vars1[1])), ','.join((vars2[0], a2, vars2[1]))))
```

In other words, values in the form `('x1,<a1>,x2', 'y1,<a2>,y2')` for all `(<a1>, <a2>)` in the cartesian product of the set `{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'}` with itself, which is indeed what `itertools.product` is meant for.

Result:

```
[('x1,a,x2', 'y1,a,y2'),
 ('x1,a,x2', 'y1,b,y2'),
 ('x1,a,x2', 'y1,c,y2'),
 ('x1,a,x2', 'y1,d,y2'),
 ('x1,b,x2', 'y1,a,y2'),
 ('x1,b,x2', 'y1,b,y2'),
 ('x1,b,x2', 'y1,c,y2'),
 ('x1,b,x2', 'y1,d,y2'),
 ('x1,c,x2', 'y1,a,y2'),
 ('x1,c,x2', 'y1,b,y2'),
 ('x1,c,x2', 'y1,c,y2'),
 ('x1,c,x2', 'y1,d,y2'),
 ('x1,d,x2', 'y1,a,y2'),
 ('x1,d,x2', 'y1,b,y2'),
 ('x1,d,x2', 'y1,c,y2'),
 ('x1,d,x2', 'y1,d,y2')]
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for! Thanks for that and for the aclaration too. The joining process is what I couldn't replicate. Have a nice day :)